# PendingIntent from Widget lost when Service is stopped

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-pendingintent

I have a music player app with a MusicPlayingService (extending `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`) and a widget to control the service. The MusicPlayingService also have a reference to a `MusicStateManager` (create in the MusicServices onCreate) which Implements "`MediaSessionCompat.Callback`" and handles all callbacks from the current MediaSession: `mSession.setCallback(MusicStateManager);`

```
public class MusicPlayingService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat implements
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "MusicPlayingService started");

    .....

    mPlayerStateManager = new MusicStateManager(this);

    .....
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mPlayerStateManager.getSession(), intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

My Widget then has a bunch of Pending Intents which are sent to the `MusicPlayingService` and handled by the `MusicStateManager`. Everything works great.

```
public class MusicStateManager extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback {

....

public MusicStateManager(@NonNull MusicStateManager argService) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setting service");
    mPlayerService = argService;

    ComponentName mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(mPlayerService, HeadsetReceiver.class);
    mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(mPlayerService, SESSION_TAG, mediaButtonReceiver, null);
    mSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    PendingIntent pendingMediaButtonIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mPlayerService, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
    mSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pendingMediaButtonIntent);

    Intent toggleIntent = new Intent(NotificationPlayer.toggleAction);
    PendingIntent pendingToggleIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mPlayerService, 0, toggleIntent, 0);
    mSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pendingToggleIntent);

    mSession.setCallback(this);
    mSession.setActive(true);

}

   /**
     * Callback method called from MusicStateManager whenever the music is about to play.
     */
    public void onPlay() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPlay");

        .......
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomAction(String action, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "received action: " + action); // NoI18N

        if (ACTION_TOGGLE.equals(action)) {
            mPlayerService.toggle();
        }
    }
```

The thing is. If I force stop the app the Music service shuts down (obviously). If I then press a button on my widget it starts my service again (I can see it from the various Log.d(...) in LogCat. However, the PendingIntent from the widget is lost, and never handled.

This has the strange implications to a user. Most of the time the buttons on a widget will work (when the service is running). However, sometimes (when the service is not running) the buttons will do nothing on the first press, but if you press them again they will work (because the first press started the service, but failed to handle the intent.

Any idea how I can debug this problem and see what happens to my PendingIntent?

Comment: Your code doesn't include where you set up the PendingIntents for your widget. Also, you're calling `setMediaButtonReceiver` multiple times, which just overrides the previously set value and is only used for [restarting playback from media buttons](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setMediaButtonReceiver(android.app.PendingIntent)), which wouldn't be invoked or change the behavior of your widget at all. Can you include your widget code and whatever `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` or `Service.onStartCommand()` that is triggered?

Comment: I was just adding everything you asked for. However, when I was about to copy/paste my PendingIntents I noticed that I was using the applicationContext as the context. This turned out to be the problem! The reason it was hard for me to debug was because when the application was started it also started the MusicService, and from LogCat it looked like the MusicService was starting up correctly.

Comment: Okay, I'm still not sure what `PendingIntent` you are using with your widget's `RemoteViews` - I expected the code that includes [setOnClickPendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create `PendingIntent`s for media playback is with [MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html#buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(android.content.Context,%20long)). This allows you to pass in a `PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_` constant that will trigger the correct callback.

```
PendingIntent playPendingIntent = MediaButtonReceiver
  .buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY);
```

It seems you already have the correct `MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent()` call in `onStartCommand()`, but you should also make sure when you create your `MediaSessionCompat` that you enable the correct actions by calling `setPlaybackState()`:

```
// Ideally, you should keep a reference to this Builder to update it,
// rather than create it from scratch each time
PlaybackStateCompat.Builder playbackStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
  .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
              PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);
mSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateBuilder.build());
```

As `MediaSessionCompat` by default does not allow any media buttons. By ensuring that you support `ACTION_PLAY` directly from instantiation, you ensure that the very first `MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent()` correctly calls your `MediaSessionCompat.Callback`.